# React 0.14-RC-1 -- OnMouseEnter & OnMouseLeave -- Change state / style

Tags: d3.js, reactjs

> **I am trying to change the opacity of an element, per mouseEnter and mouseLeave events:**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import d3 from 'd3';
import Bar from './Bar';
import lodash from 'lodash';
```

---

```
export default class DataSeries extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    availableHeight: PropTypes.number,
    data: PropTypes.array,
    height: PropTypes.number,
    offset: PropTypes.number,
    width: PropTypes.number
  }
```

---

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = ({
      opacity: 1
    });
  }
```

---

```
  onMouseEnterHandler() {
    this.setState({ opacity: 0.5 });
  }

  onMouseLeaveHandler() {
    this.setState({ opacity: 1 });
  }
```

---

```
  render() {
    const props = this.props;
    const yScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(this.props.data)])
      .range([0, this.props.height]);

    const xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .domain(d3.range(this.props.data.length))
      .rangeRoundBands([0, this.props.width], 0.05);

    const colors = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, this.props.data.length])
      .range(['#FFB832', '#C61C6F']);

    const bars = lodash.map(this.props.data, function(point, index) {
      return (
        <Bar height={ yScale(point) } width={ xScale.rangeBand() }
                  offset={ xScale(index) } availableHeight={ props.height }
                  color={ colors(point) } key={ index }
                  onMouseEnter={ () => this.onMouseEnterHandler() }
                  onMouseLeave={ () => this.onMouseLeaveHandler() }
                  style = { { opacity: this.state.opacity } } <-- error points here
        />
      );
    });
```

---

```
    return (
      <g>{ bars }</g>
    );
  }
}
```

---

```
DataSeries.defaultPropTypes = {
  title: '',
  data: []
};
```

> I am receiving the error:
>
> **TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined(…)**

Answer (score 0):

I see one issue is 'this' needs to be passed in. The other change is probably optional.

```
    let vm = this;
    let bars = lodash.map(this.props.data, function(point, index, vm) {
        let opacity = { opacity: vm.state.opacity };
        return (
            <Bar height={ yScale(point) } width={ xScale.rangeBand() }
                                offset={ xScale(index) } availableHeight={ props.height }
                                color={ colors(point) } key={ index }
                                onMouseEnter={ vm.onMouseEnterHandler }
                                onMouseLeave={ vm.onMouseLeaveHandler }
                                style = { opacity }
            />
        );
    });
```

Comment: Well the error went away, but it is not hitting the event functions.